# How to correctly use left join in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing an SQL select query that would retrieve all the names of students that are registered in a course that includes the word "Development" in the couse_name field.

I'm newbie here, and here's my SQL code:

```
select firstname, lastname
FROM students INNER JOIN registrations
ON students.student_id = registrations.student_id
and course_name  = registrations.course_name LIKE '%Development%';
```

It is wrong I know, I want to know how to use left join correctly in order to retrieve valid data.
I've attached some screenshots for the tables.

Students Table:

[image: Students Table]

Courses Table:

[image]

Registrations Table:

[image]

Comment: Most people here want formatted text instead of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query

```
select students .firstname, students.lastname
FROM students INNER JOIN registrations
ON students.student_id = registrations.student_id
inner join courses on courses.course_code=registrations.course_code
where course.course_name LIKE '%Development%';
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked and it's exactly as I wanted it to be.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an IN clause and an INNER JOIN, not a left join:

```
select s.*
from students s
where
  student_id IN (
    select student_id
    from registrations r inner join courses c
         on r.course_code = c.course_code
    where
      c.course_name like '%Development%'
  )
```

the subquery will return all `student_id` from all `registrations` where the `course_name` contains the word `Development`. The outer query will return all students informations from those `student_id`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer it, it worked but unfortunately this is way too advanced for my project.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a query which will show each student and whether or not he be registered for the course, you could use a `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```
SELECT s.firstname,
       s.lastname,
       CASE WHEN r.student_id IS NOT NULL
            THEN 'registered'
            ELSE 'not registered' END AS status
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN registrations r
    ON s.student_id = r.student_id
LEFT JOIN courses c
    ON c.course_code = r.course_code AND
       c.course_name  LIKE '%Development%';
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer it, it worked but unfortunately this is way too advanced for my project.